# Upgraded to AppCompat v22.1.0 and now getting "removing attribute" error

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I've just upgraded my app to use AppCompat v22.1.0 and I'm getting the following exception from the AppCompat layout XML file:

```
removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginEnd
    from <ImageView>
removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:textAlignment
    from <android.support.v7.internal.widget.DialogTitle>
removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layoutDirection
    from <LinearLayout>
```

[image]

I upgraded to version v1.8 of the JDK and does not work either.

Comment: Can you post the problematic XML part of the layout please?

Comment: updated with screenshoot, the error is in the AppCompat.

Comment: Follow this issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=164673

Comment: I can not wait, this will have to be corrected immediately, I have to compile and I can not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See discussion on https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=164673

You have a couple of options:

- Set `Preferences > Android > Build > Build output` to `Normal` or `Silent`. `Verbose` is causing the problem.
- Force SDK Build Tools 21.1.2 for AppCompat project only in project.properties, see https://github.com/dandar3/android-support-v7-appcompat/blob/master/project.properties

You can have as many SDK Build Tools installed, you can specify a version per project or otherwise it will pick up the latest.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by now uninstalling the "SDK v22.0.1 Build Tools" and install a previous version.

Comment: you should be using latest `Android API 22` for compiling and latest `build tools v 22.0.1` for building the app. Another important thing is that whole `Android World` is migrating to `Android studio`, so you also should stop using eclipse and start using `Android Studio`